# ePub navMap element error

Tags: itunes, epub

I have been trying to convert my docx file to epub but having a problem in the validation of epub in the itunes producer and also on online epub validations,

the error is

"A.epub: OPS/toc.ncx(2): element "navMap" not allowed here; expected the element end-tag or element "navList" or "pageList"

i dont have any idea to solve this problem, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to show us the ncx file, or at least more of it. First boil it down to the smallest case that produces the error. By the way, in doing that, you'll find the problem yourself. That's called "debugging".

Comment: Thanks but i myself solved the problem. Actually what was happening is my epub creator was adding <navMap> element after each of the chapters  field but in epub 3.0, it should be used only in starting and endings.